# AEM JSON Endpoint

Tags: json, aem, sightly

I'm essentially trying to create an endpoint in AEM which will show certain data about the authored content (what is it, modified date, etc.) with type `application/json`.

An example would be `www.example.com/content/jsonData[.json|.html]` which would display/return `{'lastModifiedDate': '<date>', 'content': '<content>'}`

This would be an HTL (Javascript) component, not a JSP component or SlingResource.

Comment: What's wrong with the existing OOTB json selector? You can write a custom selector to modify the JSON data using conventional servlets anyway.

Comment: could you provide a link on how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Add a json.jsp to the root of the page template (http://adobeaemtips.blogspot.ca/2014/06/jsonjsp.html).

To grab content from a component on the page, add the following to the JSP:

```
String path = currentPage.getPath() + "/jcr:content/<component>";
writer.key("data");
String data = resourceResolver.getResource(path).adaptTo(Node.class).getProperty(<property name>).getString();
writer.value(data);
```

Comment: Writing scriplets in your JSPs is a bad idea. You're much better off creating a SlingServlet with a "json" selector.

Comment: Could you provide a resource on how to this please?

Comment: This is an excellent resource on writing out JSON from a Resource: http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2015/12/converting-aem-sling-resources-to-json

Comment: As far as writing a SlingServlet is concerned you can have a look at the Sling documentation: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html

Comment: Thanks for the resources they look helpful, however in my case I can't write SlingResource or java classes. It's either jsp, or HTML/json for component design. This is just a project constraint.